# Secure way to use remote API keys with react-native?

Tags: react-native

I am developing a frontend with react-native, and I need use static maps form Google or MapBox. To store Api key at develop time I am using a .env file with react-native-config but their readme say:

> Keep in mind this module doesn't obfuscate or encrypt secrets for
>   packaging, so do not store sensitive keys in .env. It's basically
>   impossible to prevent users from reverse engineering mobile app
>   secrets, so design your app (and APIs) with that in mind.

So, is there some way to obfuscate Api keys on react-native (for Android and IOS)?

Or the only way is create an endpoint at the backend doing proxy functions to add here the api key, something like:

```
import express, { Application } from "express";
import * as https from "https";

const app: Application = express();

app.get("/map", (request, response) => {
    const params: string = "Get the params from request";
    https.request(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?key=${process.env.API_KEY}&${params}`, (result) => {
        result.pipe(response, { end: true });
    });
});
```

I can see several drawback, I will consume more bandwidth from my hosting and I will slow down of my application (first a request from the frontend to the backend, after a request from the backend to Google static maps, after the backend gets the response from Google maps and at end the frontend gets the response from the backend)

PS: Keep in mind I am talking about Google maps static and not google maps sdk Android or google maps sdk IOS.

Answer (score 4):

MapBox have a good support. So after asking them here is the response:

> Unfortunately, the proxy approach you've described is a violation of
>   our Terms of Service.
>
> I want to make sure you have seen our guide for [using Mapbox
>   securely](https://www.mapbox.com/help/how-to-use-mapbox-securely/#access-tokens). It includes a lot of great tips and best practices for
>   managing your account.
>
> In our experience, [cycling tokens](https://www.mapbox.com/help/how-access-tokens-work/#creating-and-managing-access-tokens) on the customer side paired
>   with a general awareness of what's happening (by monitoring your
>   account statistics) has been sufficient to control and limit access
>   most of the time. If you're in need of frequent, programmatic access
>   token rotation, you can utilize our [Tokens API](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/accounts/#tokens) for that.
>
> All this being said, restricting tokens by app id *is* on our radar as
>   it's a common request we receive. Our engineering team is hard at work
>   to make a whitelisting feature possible for our customers. Until then,
>   if you ever have questions about [your statistics](https://www.mapbox.com/account/statistics) or are seeing
>   unexpected stats. We're always happy to work with you and can look
>   into the any concerning usage patterns for you.
>
> If you have other questions about your account statistics or invoices,
>   be sure to check out our [Statistics FAQs](https://www.mapbox.com/help/statistics-invoices/#statistics-faqs).
>
> Hope this helps!